# Why does this lambda expression include closure?

Tags: c#, lambda, closures

I am using a class from the UWP (universal Windows 10 apps) Community Toolkit called `WeakEventListener` (source code available [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp/Helpers/WeakEventListener.cs#L62)) to subscribe to events while allowing the listener to be finalized by the garbage collector, since this has been a source of memory leaks in my project in the past. One thing that is absolutely critical is that delegates assigned to OnEventAction and OnDetachAction must not contain closure (i.e., a strong reference to the listener, or `this`). But it appears that I am always getting closure, even if I don't use `this` within the delegate (which are usually lambda expressions). Here is an example lambda expression (inside the constructor of class TransitMap, which has a private method called AddIns_CollectionChanged):

```
addInsListener.OnEventAction = (map, obj, e) => map.AddIns_CollectionChanged(obj, e);
```

But when I enforce delegates without closure in my WeakEventListener class like this:

```
private Action<TInstance, TSource, TEventArgs> _OnEventAction;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the method to call when the event fires.
    /// </summary>
    public Action<TInstance, TSource, TEventArgs> OnEventAction
    {
        get { return _OnEventAction; }
        set
        {
            if (value?.Target != null)
                throw new Exception("Any delegate passed to a WeakEventListener must be static, otherwise a memory leak exists.");
            _OnEventAction = value;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the delegate always has a non-null Target, even if it doesn't reference `this` within itself! Does anyone know why this would be?

---

Update: Below is some of the relevant code from my class, the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.

```
public sealed class TransitMap : UserControl
{
    private ObservableCollection<TransitMapAddInBase> AddIns = new ObservableCollection<TransitMapAddInBase>();
    public TransitMap()
    {
        WeakEventListener<TransitMap, object, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs> addInsListener = new WeakEventListener<TransitMap, object, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(this);
        //Problem line. Lambda expression holds up a strong reference to 'this' (in its Target) despite using a parameter for the listener instead of this.
        addInsListener.OnEventAction = (map, obj, e) => map.AddIns_CollectionChanged(obj, e);
        AddIns.CollectionChanged += addInsListener.OnEvent;
    }


    private void AddIns_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an actual minimal repro that demonstrates the problem. For instance, we do not know if AddinCollectionChanged is generic, if the current class is generic, and so on.